# Cropping and uploading images in angular

Tags: angularjs, crop, image-uploading

I want to crop images in angular and upload them. Currently i am using angular-img-cropper but there are some issues with it. It does not support multiple instances on the same page and the cropped image is also clickable. Can someone suggest me how i can crop and upload images in angular or any other tools/libraries/directives that do the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngImgCropExtended](https://github.com/vogloblinsky/ngImgCropExtended) for the image cropping and [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) to upload your image. They all support multiple instances on the same page.

Comment: Hi @Danny Pranoto. Is it usable on mobile devices too?

Comment: sure, i've tested it in android device using mobile browsers